# WM6.5 embedded Internet Explorer finder scrolling

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm writing a .NET 3.5 application targetted for Windows Mobile 6.5.  My application uses an embedded IE control to display content.

The IE application allows the user to finger scroll around the webpage (i.e. touch the screen and drag instead of using the scrollbar).  My IE control has a scrollbar and when I emulate the gesture, I highlight text instead of scrolling.

Is there a way to add finger gesture support to an embedded IE control?

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

The was a fix to the web browser control used in .Net CF 3.5. This fix has proper scrolling enabled. See here for more information:

http://blogs.msdn.com/raffael/archive/2009/09/29/microsoft-released-a-hotfix-for-netcf-v3-5-on-windows-mobile-6-1-4-onwards-to-address-basic-functionalities-of-webbrowser-control.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In the time since I posted this, I did run across that article.  I went on to Marketplace and got the update and my cgacutil reports the same version mentioned in the article.  However, I still get the same behavior as before where I can't use gestures.  I also don't recall not being able to click links, I'm using an old emulator without the patch and I can still click the links.  My understanding is I don't need to update anything on the development side for this to work.